# How to convert tex into pdf for nature using pandoc

Tags: pdf, latex, pandoc, tex

I would like to convert tex to pdf for nature using pandoc.

I installed texlive2017 and pandoc (in docker container).

```
$ tex -v
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 D.E. Knuth.

$ pandoc -v
pandoc 1.12.4.2
Compiled with texmath 0.6.6.1, highlighting-kate 0.5.8.5.
Syntax highlighting is supported for the following languages:
actionscript, ada, apache, asn1, asp, awk, bash, bibtex, boo, c, changelog,
clojure, cmake, coffee, coldfusion, commonlisp, cpp, cs, css, curry, d,
diff, djangotemplate, doxygen, doxygenlua, dtd, eiffel, email, erlang,
fortran, fsharp, gcc, gnuassembler, go, haskell, haxe, html, ini, isocpp,
java, javadoc, javascript, json, jsp, julia, latex, lex, literatecurry,
literatehaskell, lua, makefile, mandoc, markdown, matlab, maxima, metafont,
mips, modelines, modula2, modula3, monobasic, nasm, noweb, objectivec,
objectivecpp, ocaml, octave, pascal, perl, php, pike, postscript, prolog,
pure, python, r, relaxngcompact, restructuredtext, rhtml, roff, ruby, rust,
scala, scheme, sci, sed, sgml, sql, sqlmysql, sqlpostgresql, tcl, texinfo,
verilog, vhdl, xml, xorg, xslt, xul, yacc, yaml
Default user data directory: /root/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2014 John MacFarlane
```

And I installed the nature package.
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nature/

```
$ tlmgr install nature
```

Then I downloaded http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nature/nature-template.tex and converted it into pdf using lualatex command. It worked well.

```
$ lualatex nature-template.tex
```

Then I tried the same using pandoc.

```
$ pandoc nature-template.tex --latex-engine=lualatex -o sample.pdf
```

This was converted into pdf, but the figure block in tex was not output in pdf.

How do I properly convert a tex file into pdf using pandoc?

---

2017-11-15 15:05) edited
I reinstalled latest pandoc.

```
$ pandoc -v
pandoc 2.0.2
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.3, texmath 0.10, skylighting 0.4.3.2
Default user data directory: /root/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2017 John MacFarlane
```

And tried again.

```
$ pandoc nature-template.tex --pdf-engine=lualatex -o sample.pdf
```

The result was same.

Comment: two things: 1. use the most current pandoc version, 2. what do you gain by generating the PDF with pandoc which simply uses latex under the hood?

Comment: I will try to use pandoc the most current version.

Comment: I am making the service which converts html to tex, or tex to html and tex to pdf on Ruby on Rails. So I think pandoc is good.

Comment: for  html to tex and tex to html pandoc is great. for tex to pdf I'd just call out to pdflatex or xelatex directly, pandoc won't preserve all layouting TeX commands.

Comment: I will convert tex to pdf using lualatex directly. Thanks.